# Why is scrollbar orientation horizontal instead of vertical?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've built a `Listbox` and bound it to a horizontal `Scrollbar`, but when I run it, it is strangely displayed on the screen.

Useful code snippet:

```
listframel = Frame(root)
listframel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW, rowspan=5)
listframel.configure(bg="white")

listframel.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4), weight=1)
listframel.grid_columnconfigure((0,), weight=1)

scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(listframel)
scrollbar2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

listbox = Listbox(listframel, xscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=conforta, borderwidth=0)
listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scrollbar2.config(command=listbox.xview)
```

Here is a useful screenshot:

[image: App screenshot]

The scrollbar works as intended, but does not gets displayed correctly. Is the issue of my OS or my code?

Comment: Set `orient='horizontal'` on `scrollbar2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the horizontal scrollbar to be horizontal, by setting `orient='horizontal'` when creating the widget:

```
scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(listframel, orient='horizontal')
```